# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS blank Icon error

Tags: display, icons

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  (I am coming from windows) and installing a few apps like unity tweak tool and app grid , I checked for updates and updated the display drivers and after restarting all i see is blank icons .

I am very new to this and would apreciate the help.These are some blank icons and also look at the top bar it also looks wierd.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your theme to the default theme such as **Ambiance**. Mostly, you must have changed to a theme where the icon pack doesn't provide a proper icon to the app in the launcher.

Changing themes is again available in Unity tweak tool.